# c++,bitmap won't show?

Tags: c++, winapi, bitmap

The bitmap will not display when the left mouse button is clicked.
I'm using visual c++ express

```
HDC DC, memDC;

switch(message) {
case WM_CREATE:
        hBit1 = LoadBitmap(hInst, "C:\New folder (2)\MyBP1.bmp");
        break;

case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
            DC = GetDC(hwnd);
            memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(DC);
        SelectObject (memDC, hBit1);
        BitBlt(DC, LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), 27, 59, memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, DC);
        DeleteDC(memDC);
        break;
```

I'm not sure exactly whats wrong with the code.
Theres no errors displayed in visual c++ express
If the code is all wrong would someone point me in the right direction

Comment: By no errors being displayed, do you mean no compiler errors/warnings, or no errors from function calls failing (and you checking for failure of course)?

Comment: no errors from compiler

Comment: Well, get on that function failure checking then :)

Comment: The bitmap will just be nuked by the next paint cycle. A static control is what you want. And why did you neglect error checking. If you had just done that the computer would have solved it for you. Why do so many people not check for errors?

Comment: I just wanted to convert my answer to a comment so more people don't suggest the same. I asked OP to try `"C:\\New folder (2)\\MyBP1.bmp"` but that didn't help.

Comment: Even though the answer's gone now, it's important to emphasize: "It's pointless asking for more help until you add comprehensive error checking to all your api calls" – David Heffernan

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LoadBitmap` is only for loading bitmaps that are stored as resources in your executable or a DLL.

To load a bitmap from a BMP file, you want to use `LoadImage` with the `LR_LOADFROMFILE` flag, something like this:

```
bmp = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(0, filename, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
```

As an aside, you probably don't really want to do the displaying directly in response to `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`. Instead, you normally want to record the position, possibly set a flag to indicate that the bitmap should be displayed, and call `InvalidateRect` to invalidate your client rectangle -- then do the actual drawing in response to `WM_PAINT`.